# Can't compare 2 dates in oracle correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, date, comparison

I have this sql query which retrieve records until  **12/7/2016** the problem is, oracle returns records which is from 12/6/2016 and below. May I ask is this the correct behavior?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NO
FROM TBL_CLIENT_FINANCIAL_ACTIVITY cfa
WHERE CAST(tran_date as DATE) <= TO_DATE('12/07/2016');
```

Comment: Do `SELECT ACCOUNT_NO, tran_date FROM ...`. Correct result?

Comment: Yes. It does reflects correct result. The issue is the date comparison.

Comment: Move `CAST(tran_date as DATE)` and  `TO_DATE('12/07/2016')` from WHERE to the select list. What happens?

Comment: To clarify: Are you saying that the exact date 12/07/2016 is excluded, as if you had written `<` instead of `<=` ?

Comment: Outputs the same result.

Comment: @HenningKoehler, yes that's what I'm trying to say. If I instead use '12/08/2016' I could see results from '12/07/2016'

Comment: Hmm.. my only guess at this point is that it's related to [timezones](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm) configured in the server and client, which may lead you to get dates of 12/07 in the result on the server side, but they display as 12/06 on the client side. You may be able to check this by returning the date of the account_no tuple both as string and as date type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using MM/DD/YYYY? Declare it in your to_date().

```
to_date('12/07/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Also, let's trunc that new date to match the date you have stated, otherwise those leftover hours minutes seconds are later than your to_date value.

```
trunc(CAST(tran_date as DATE)) <= to_date('12/07/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: The trunc() function worked. I guess casting timestamp to date is not enough.